# Inserting text into an image with jQuery

Tags: jquery, image

I've been searching for a couple of hours now, and I still can't seem to find a nice jquery plugin (or anything else), that would help me to insert the text into a picture.

I don't want the text to be "over" the image. I want that the text would become a part of an image. I will be using it to make motivational / demotivational posters online. Besides the text problem, I also can't figure out a way to make the black "padding".

I would really appreciate if you could give me some pointers or tips on how to approach this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery is for UI processing - that beaing, processing things at the user interface level - in the browser. What you want should be created on the server side - using [PHPs imagemagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) library for example

Comment: That explains a lot! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to edit an image using javascript. You might have to use some server side language for image editing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have good HTML5 support this is possible using a [`Canvas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Canvas) element.

You can use:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, dx, dy);
```

to render the contents of an `<img>` tag into the canvas at a specified offset (to give you a border), and:

```
ctx.fillText(...);
```

to add your own text on top.

See the [W3C spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#images).

If you don't have HTML5, it'll have to be done server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/). You might need to dynamically load the image and create a new image as your output.

Otherwise, HTML 5 would be an option or a server side solution will be required as mentioned by the others.

Comment: Very good option, but don't works on all the browsers and older browsers.

Comment: Raphaël currently supports Firefox 3.0+, Safari 3.0+, Chrome 5.0+, Opera 9.5+ and Internet Explorer 6.0+. What older than that do you expect for current technology? If you need advanced features, you have to forget the older browsers and force them to catch up with technology.